# how to get group name after group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I want to use group names after the group_by function.
The following is my example for illustration.

table 1

| year | size |
| --- | --- |
| 1990 | 4 |
| 1990 | 3 |
| 1991 | 5 |
| 1991 | 5 |

table 2

| year | breaks_1 | breaks_2 | breaks_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 1991 | 1 | 5 | 6 |

I want to create a new column, **interval**, for table 1, showing for each year which interval the size is in, as the following augmented table 1 shows.

augmented table 1

| year | size | interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | 4 | 2 |
| 1990 | 3 | 2 |
| 1991 | 1.6 | 1 |
| 1991 | 5 | 2 |

Please note the intervals depends on the specified years.  For example, for year 1990, the intervals are [1,3] and [3,6], while for year 1991, the intervals are [1,5] and [5,6].

I guess I can do it in the following way.

```
table1 <- table1 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(interval = cut(
                      size, 
                      breaks =table2[year==group_name,2:4]))
```

But I don't know how to get the group's name in the **cut** function.

Comment: Do the intervals for each year depend on the values in size column? Or are the intervals specified manually?

Comment: Which of your tables is `table1`? What do you mean by the “group’s name”? What, _precisely_, is your expected output?

Comment: @AbdurRohman it is specified manually as in table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a way to do it with dplyr:

```
table1 <-
  tibble::tribble(
  ~year, ~size,
  1990L,    4,
  1990L,    3,
  1991L,    1.6,
  1991L,    5L
  )

table2 <-
tibble::tribble(
  ~year, ~breaks_1, ~breaks_2, ~breaks_3,
  1990L,        1L,        3L,        6L,
  1991L,        1L,        5L,        6L
  )

table1 %>% 
  left_join(table2) %>% 
  mutate(
    interval = case_when(
      size >= breaks_1 & size < breaks_2 ~ 1,
      size >= breaks_2 & size < breaks_3 ~ 2
    )
  )

Joining, by = "year"
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise: 
   year  size breaks_1 breaks_2 breaks_3 interval
  <int> <dbl>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <dbl>
1  1990   4          1        3        6        2
2  1990   3          1        3        6        2
3  1991   1.6        1        5        6        1
4  1991   5          1        5        6        2
```